# Please explain the copy backup types

Tags: command-line, files, backup, coreutils

The following options are available for the --backup option:

```
  none, off       never make backups (even if --backup is given)
  numbered, t     make numbered backups
  existing, nil   numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
  simple, never   always make simple backups
```

1. First, how exactly is a simple backup defined? It's confusing because the alias to 'simple' is 'never', why is that and how does 'simple' relate to 'never'?
2. How does existing differ from simple backups? Simple backups still seem to create a backup of existing files. Again, the alas is 'nil' and it's not clear why or how this relates to 'existing' files?
3. Numbered backups is pretty straightforward, it would seem to be a shortcut for `--suffix=<auto increment integer>`. This is not a question, but correct if wrong.
4. The option for `none, off` may be given for completeness or for unique cases.

Comment: What application are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

These can be understood a bit more easily once one comes upon these lines in [the GNU Coreutils documentation of backup options](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Backup-options.html) (which are not unique to `cp`, but shared with `mv` and other tools from coreutils):

> This option corresponds to the Emacs variable ‘`version-control`’; the values for *method* are the same as those used in Emacs. This option also accepts more descriptive names.

Once you understand that the method names originated in the context of *version control* for an OS masquerading as a text editor (which itself predates the more popular version control systems extant today), things will fall into place:

- "never" do full version control - just make a simple backup of the last version instead of having multiple versions.
- version control is "off" - don't even bother with the last version, so no backup file at all (which is sometimes desirable with a text editor).

As for `existing`, note that it isn't talking about "existing *files*" - it's talking about *existing **backups*** ("if numbered backups exist"). So say there's a file `a.b`, and a backup of that needs to be made. Then check if the numbered backup file `a.b.~1~` exists. If it does, continue using the numbered backup method. If it doesn't, make a simple backup.